# PHP Using curl with torcache

Tags: php, html, curl

Hi I want to be able to do the following:

```
<?php

function get_data($url)
{
  $ch = curl_init();
  $timeout = 5;
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $data;
}
$data = get_data('https://torcache.net/torrent/7975CDEEDCEC6092729DAEAE302CB9BD7D633B0B.torrent');

?>
```

However it seems that torcache is returning a html page and then the torrent is seved a few seconds after, is there anyway for curl to get the actual torrent? At the minute $data just contains the html page torcache returns?

Attempted to set referer as: 
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://torcache.net/torrent/7975CDEEDCEC6092729DAEAE302CB9BD7D633B0B.torrent');

But not working, I get this response:

```
<head><title>302 Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>302 Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.2.0</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

SOLVED:

```
function get_data($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://torcache.net/');
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING,"gzip");
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
```

Added "curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING,"gzip");" this also as the data was gzipped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure out how they check whether to server the HTML page or the torrent file. My guess is the `HTTP_REFERER`. Spoof it.

Comment: There's some javascript in there, will that not be serving the download?

Comment: Doesn't look like it. Open it up with the Chrome inspector or Firebug on and go to the Network / Net tab. The URL is the same.

Comment: So the only thing I can see is that the mime type is different? Looking on how to spoof this but can't see anything :(

Comment: You don't send a Mime-Type .. the server sets it for you. Have you tried setting the HTTP_REFERER header?

Comment: Yeah its not working it just sends back a "302 Found" Not quite sure what I'm supposed to set referer to. Atm it is:   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://torcache.net/torrent/7975CDEEDCEC6092729DAEAE302CB9BD7D633B0B.torrent');

Answer (score 0):

If `$_GET['tor']` contains the info_hash from torrentz.eu site, this should do the trick.

```
$ch = curl_init('http://torcache.net/torrent/'.strtoupper($_GET['tor']).'.torrent');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, null);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, TRUE);                                                                 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-bittorrent','Referer: http://torcache.net/torrent/'.strtoupper($_GET['tor']).'.torrent')); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://torcache.net/torrent/'.strtoupper($_GET['tor']).'.torrent'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,"gzip");
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
```

Comment: Doing a curl request by using something from $_GET without sanitazing it first looks like it might be a security problem, maybe not that serious this time, but it's a bad habit.

Comment: Thanks, I did get it to work in the end using a similar process, I'll post my code for reference when I get home